# How do I access a PC network share from an Android device when my Windows login is associated with my Microsoft Account?

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, android, file-sharing

I am trying to access shared files on my PC from my Android phone using CX File Explorer. Both devices are on the same LAN, and the credentials I am using are my Microsoft account credentials since my Windows login is tied to them. So far, I have not been successful.

What do I need to do to access them?

Comment: On your windows computer, while logged in, if you open a command prompt and type echo %USERNAME% it should tell you the username you need for your phone. Password is that of your ms account. That should work.

Comment: @LPChip This worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. I've posted it as an answer too, so you can mark this solved. That way, others know you no longer need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your windows computer, while logged in, if you open a command prompt and
type `echo %USERNAME%` it should tell you the username you need for your phone.

Password is that of your ms account. That should work.